# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length') at countPositivesSumNegatives (test.js:10:24)

Tags: javascript

i am facing problem with this code

`

```
yofunction countPositivesSumNegatives(input) {
  // your code here
  let sumPositive = 0;
  let someNegative = 0;
  
  if(input != null && input.length === 0){
return []};
  
  for(let i=0; i<input.length; i++){
    if (input[i]>0){
      sumPositive++;
      }
      else if (input[i] < 0){
     someNegative += input[i];
  }
//     else{
//       return [];
//     }
    
    
  }
    
     return [sumPositive, someNegative]
  
}
```

whenever i run it , i get this message "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')
at countPositivesSumNegatives (test.js:10:24)"   the problem is from codewars.  i didnt understand what does this mean , please help me

i wanted my code to give my an emypty array when the input is emty or [0,0];

Comment: You don't handle the case where `input` is null properly.  You return empty array if (input is not null and input is empty), but not when input is null.  Consider `if (input === null || input.length === 0) return []`

Answer (score 0):

Why this block of code?

```
if(input != null && input.length === 0){
return []};
```

With this, if you used `input` as null then you will get the error.

Change it to this:

```
if(input == null || input.length === 0){
return []};
```

**This is the full code**

```js
function countPositivesSumNegatives(input) {
  // your code here
  let sumPositive = 0;
  let someNegative = 0;
  
  if(input == null || input.length === 0){
return [0, 0]};
  
  for(let i=0; i<input.length; i++){
    if (input[i]>0){
      sumPositive++;
      }
      else if (input[i] < 0){
     someNegative += input[i];
  }
//     else{
//       return [];
//     }
    
    
  }
    
     return [sumPositive, someNegative]
  
}
console.log(countPositivesSumNegatives(null));
```